# Redis under Classic ASP(VBScript)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, redis

I'm developing a website under Classic ASP(espeically VBScript). To enhance site performance, I'm considering to use Redis(key-value database). From http://redis.io/clients, there is no client with VBScript. As a research, I have to develop a service/COM to fit into my requirement.

Does anybody has such experience? or maybe you can share some code/tip. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I have researched the same for memcached/couchbase.

You have a few options: you can look for a javascript (node.js?) implementation. Classic ASP can also be written in javascript instead of VBscript. It might be possible to port the code to classic ASP.

I would advise you to use a WSC to encapsulate the code. A WSC is like a COM component, except written in vbscript or jscript. You can use it exactly like a COM object, but you can dynamically change the code without re-registering it every time. Here is some more info:

http://aspalliance.com/414_Windows_Scripting_Components_WSC_in_ASP
http://precompiled.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/hmac-sha1-encryptie-onder-classic-asp/
(note that the links to the WSC's no longer work, but there are mirrors in the comments)

The second path you can take is to find a .NET client and wrap it with a COM wrapper. If you have the source code and Visual Studio it should be possible to expose the .NET component as COM. Some more info on that is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285.aspx

Good luck!
Erik

**UPDATE: I have witten an extended Redis COM component for Classic ASP. It can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/erik4/redis-com-client).**

Comment: Thanks EriK. I prefer the last suggestion(.NET to COM). For Redis, there are four data types: string, list, hashtable, set, sorted set. string is simple, the other types is a bit compliated. For example, for hashtable, how to handle get/set(how to handle scripting.dictionary)?

Comment: I see what you mean; The .NET component takes a .NET dictionary as a parameter or property, and you need to "translate" a vbscript dictionary to a .NET dictionary you can use... Not sure how this goes, but it might just work "out of the box" I can imagine .NET has dynamic types to handle vbscript types. I would just experiment a little, see what you bump into.

Comment: Hi Gary, I've just written a small POC for classic asp and redis. It seems to work, I van SET and GET keys. Interested in the steps I had to take?

Comment: Gary, are you still interested in showing those steps for classic asp and redis?