# Using Redis from Classic ASP.. without COM?

Tags: node.js, vbscript, asp-classic, redis

We're looking at introducing Redis within our application stack as a high performance key/value store, and I've been investigating ways of interacting with Redis from Classic ASP. Unfortunately I'm not getting too far with this as the only suggested ways of implementing a client seem to revolve using a COM wrapper or similar to use a .net client.

I've seen a few references to converting a Node.JS client to run under Classic ASP but this just doesn't seem like a good way forwards given the age of Classic's JS engine.

Before we embark on this or look at writing a wrapper-rest API using node.js or similar, has anyone created a native (VBScript) client for Redis which they wouldn't mind sharing...?

I'm also exploring the idea of using a WSC as suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229734/redis-under-classic-aspvbscript?rq=1), but would greatly prefer to look at a native solution if there is one...

Comment: Have you checked out this question yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229734/redis-under-classic-aspvbscript?rq=1 it does mention the details on utilizing W3C (a non-COM object which acts like a COM object)

Comment: Thanks Rich - was looking at that as an option but still keen to explore a "native" solution if there is one.

Comment: *"... given the age of Classic's JS engine."*  Microsoft JScript 9 (released with IE 9) supports ECMA-262 5th edition. If you have IE9 or newer on your IIS server, you should be pretty up-to-date.

Comment: To come back to this, we've been experimenting with running a mixture of VBScript & Javascript in a single Classic ASP page/script.. Initial focus of this was to see if we could retrofit some sort of Handlebars template engine; which seems to work great.. Next stop is looking at whether the same approach will work for Redis :)

Answer (score 2):

I could not find anything native. So, I wrapped the StackExchange .Net client into a COM+.

If you want to take a look, this is the repo: https://github.com/dikoga/redis-com-client/

Answer (score 0):

For people stumbling on this page looking for a more recent solution; a fork of the Redis COM client with support for more commands can be found here: https://gitlab.com/erik4/redis-com-client